# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error, special-characters, token

```
a = JSON.parse('["<input class="image" type="file" name="%simg_%d"/>"]');
```

gives the above error. Can someone explain why? Is `%s` the start of some kind of special character string in json/javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't escape the quotes so you keep breaking in and out of the string which makes for invalid JSON

```
JSON.parse('["<input class=\\"image\\" type=\\"file\\" name=\\"%simg_%d\\"/>"]');
```